# Power series of a function related to Gamma function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, power-series, gamma-function

I'm having trouble solving the following exercise:

> Let $\alpha \in \mathbb C$ fixed and $f: D \to \mathbb C$  defined by $$f(z) := \frac{1}{(1-z)^\alpha}.$$
>   Let $$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(\alpha) z^n $$
>   be the power series representation of $f$. Show that for the coefficients $a_n(\alpha)$ the following holds:
>   $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_n(\alpha)}{n^{\alpha - 1}} = \frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}$$

Where $D$ denotes the unit ball and $\Gamma$ the Gamma function.
Attempt:
I assume I need to find out explicit representation of the coefficients $a_n(\alpha)$ and then show the identity using the Gauß representation of the Gamma function: $$\Gamma(s) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n! n^s}{s(s+1) \cdot \cdot \cdot (s+n)}.$$ However, I was unable to find a useful one. Expanding the function $f$ into a Taylor series didn't work out (if I did not do it wrong). Is there an easier way to find out the coefficients?

Comment: You can get the Taylor expansion with the binomial theorem.  You might need to play with it a little by collecting the negative signs together.

Comment: $a_n=(-1)^n \binom{-\alpha}{n}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* and applying the binomial identity $$\binom{-\alpha}{n}=\binom{\alpha+n-1}{n}(-1)^n$$

> we derive for $|z|<1$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$
>   \begin{align*}
> f(z)=\frac{1}{(1-z)^\alpha}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{-\alpha}{n}(-z)^n\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{\alpha+n-1}{n}z^n\\
> \end{align*}

It follows
\begin{align*}
a_n(\alpha)&=\binom{\alpha+n-1}{n}=\frac{1}{n!}(\alpha+n-1)(\alpha+n-2)\cdots\alpha\\
&=\frac{1}{n!}(\alpha+n-1)^{\underline{n}}
\end{align*}
with $z^{\underline{n}}=z(z-1)\cdots(z-n+1)$ the falling factorial.

> The following is valid
>   \begin{align*}
> \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n(\alpha)}{n^{\alpha-1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(\alpha+n-1)^{\underline{n}}}{n!n^{\alpha-1}}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>
> In order to show (1) we use a representation of the Gamma function $\Gamma(\alpha)$ according to *[C.F. Gauss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#19th_century:_Gauss.2C_Weierstrass_and_Legendre)*. We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\Gamma(\alpha)}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^\alpha n!}{\alpha(\alpha+1)\cdots(\alpha+n)}\\
> &=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^\alpha n!}{(\alpha+n)^{\underline{n+1}}}\\
> &=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n}{\alpha+n}\cdot\frac{n^{\alpha-1} n!}{(\alpha+n-1)^{\underline{n}}}\right)\\
> &=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\frac{\alpha}{n}+1}\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{\alpha-1} n!}{(\alpha+n-1)^{\underline{n}}}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{\alpha-1} n!}{(\alpha+n-1)^{\underline{n}}}}\\
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty}{\pars{-1}^{n}{-\alpha \choose n} \over n^{\alpha - 1}} & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{{\pars{-1}^{n} \over n^{\alpha - 1}}\,
{\pars{-\alpha}! \over n!\pars{-\alpha - n}!}} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{{\pars{-1}^{n} \over n^{\alpha - 1}}
\,{\Gamma\pars{1 - \alpha} \over
\Gamma\pars{n + 1}\,\Gamma\pars{1 -\alpha - n}}}
\\[5mm] & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\braces{{\pars{-1}^{n} \over n^{\alpha - 1}\,\Gamma\pars{n + 1}}\,
{\pi \over \Gamma\pars{\alpha}\sin\pars{\pi\alpha}}\,{\Gamma\pars{n + \alpha}\sin\pars{\pi\bracks{n + \alpha}} \over \pi}}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over \Gamma\pars{\alpha}}\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{{1 \over n^{\alpha - 1}}
{\Gamma\pars{n + \alpha} \over \Gamma\pars{n + 1}}}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over \Gamma\pars{\alpha}}\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{%
{1 \over n^{\alpha -1}}\,
{\root{2\pi}\pars{n + \alpha}^{n + \alpha + 1/2}\expo{-n - \alpha}  \over
\root{2\pi}\pars{n + 1}^{n + 1 + 1/2}\expo{-n - 1}}}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over \Gamma\pars{\alpha}}\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{%
{1 \over n^{\alpha -1}}\,{n^{n + \alpha + 1/2}\,\pars{1 + \alpha/n}^{n + \alpha + 1/2}  \over
n^{n + 3/2}\,\pars{1 + 1/n}^{n + 3/2}}\,\expo{1 - \alpha}}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over \Gamma\pars{\alpha}}\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{%
{\pars{1 + \alpha/n}^{n}  \over
\pars{1 + 1/n}^{n}}\,\expo{1 - \alpha}} = \bbx{1 \over \Gamma\pars{\alpha}}
\end{align}